# simply selecting a column in a specific row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ok, my frustration has hit epic proportions. I am new to Pandas and trying to use it on an excel db i have, however, i cannot seem to figure out what should be a VERY simple action.
I have a dataframe as such:

```
ID UID NAME STATE
1  123 Bob NY
1  123 Bob PA
2  124 Jim NY
2  124 Jim PA
3  125 Sue NY
```

all i need is to be able to locate and print the ID of a record by the unique combination of UID and STATE.

The closest I can come up with is this:

```
temp_db = fd_db.loc[(fd_db['UID'] == "1") & (fd_db['STATE'] == "NY")]
```

but this still grabs all UID and not ONLY the one with the STATE

Then, when i try to print the result

```
temp_db.ID.values
```

prints this:

```
['1', '1']
```

I need just the data and not the structure.

My end result needs to be just to print to the screen : 1

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hello my friend, may be you need to do fd_db['UID'] == 1 and not the string "1"

Comment: We need more information on your DataFrame, especially the dtypes. `temp_db.ID.values` How does that relate to the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because your UID condition is wrong : the UID column an Integer and you give a String.

For example when I run this :

```
df.loc[(df['UID'] == "123") & (df['STATE'] == 'NY')]
```

The output is :

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ID, UID, NAME, STATE]
Index: []
```

but when I consider UID as an Integer :

```
df.loc[(df['UID'] == 123) & (df['STATE'] == 'NY')]
```

It output :

```
   ID  UID NAME STATE
0   1  123  Bob    NY
```

I hope that will help you !

Answer (score 0):

```
fd_db.loc[(fd_db['UID'] == 123) & (fd_db['STATE'] == 'NY')]['ID'].iloc[0]
```